# how to run oracle package which is a variable?

Tags: oracle

I have package and the package is working fine

```
create or replace PACKAGE PKG_SEQ IS
st_server_site  VARCHAR2(1) := NULL;....
```

But when I see

```
select KG_SEQ.st_server_site from my_table
```

in some old code, I get error message,
can anyone help me to understand it ?

> **ST_SERVER_SITE' is not a procedure or is undefined
>   06553. 00000 -  "PLS-%s: %s**"

Comment: Is that a procedure? `ST_SERVER_SITE` is defined as a variable in your package. Can you provide us the full specification of the package and the procedure?

Comment: If you need to access that variable you can simply create function `return_st_server_site` which will return the `ST_SERVER_SITE` so that you can use it in your select, for example: `select pkg_seq.return_st_server_site() from dual`

Answer (score 0):

it seems st_server_site is not a `procedure` but a `variable` and you can not write such a select statement.

```
create or replace PACKAGE PKG_SEQ IS
  st_server_site  VARCHAR2(1) := NULL;....
 procedure pr_server_site( i_var1 number, i_var2 varchar2) is
 begin 
  ...
 end pr_server_site;

 function fn_server_site( i_var1 number, i_var2 date ) return number is
 begin 
  ...
 end fn_server_site;
end;
```

if the package were like this, you could call like the following :

```
SQL> exec PKG_SEQ.pr_server_site( &var1, '&var2' );
```

*OR*

```
SQL> var result1 number;
SQL> select PKG_SEQ.fn_server_site( col1, col2 ) into result1 from mytable; -- where col1 is of type number and col2 is of type date, columns of your table
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all the suggestions are add some function into the package.
I don't think I should have the privilege to do that . some one through the select sql to me I can run it in sql develop so I ask question in here .